# iOS 8 - 9 Upgrade testing

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, upgrade, xcode7

During QA testing of one of my iOS apps an issue has been logged when upgrading a device for iOS 8 to iOS 9. Although I have a good idea where the bug is occurring it is quite a difficult situation to test because once a physical device has been upgraded from iOS 8->9 it is not possible to roll back to 8 again to repeat the tests.

Is anyone aware of a way to perform this type of testing without having an illimited number of iPads. It is not possible using the XCode simulator obviously, and the physical device upgrade procedure prevents rolling back to a previous iOS version. Surely Apple must have some sort of provision for people in this situation but I can not find any information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No once a device is upgrade it is very hard to get it running the previous version again. Jailbreaking can help a lot in this case. Apple does not provide any mean to test this.

Comment: Once jailbreak to degrade your device, no way to access the Software updates. Apple does not support for feature updates.

Comment: I was thinking of Jailbreaking but as HariKrishnan said that would prevent the updates!